# Get foreground package name in Android 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use the code below to get the application package name.
But when I swipe the notification bar, it will take the name of the application package running in the notification bar.
Or where applications are updating the new version, it will take the name of the application package.
I tried it on Android 5 get exact results open application package name.
So how to get the name of the application package is currently running on Android open 6

```
    public static String printForegroundTask(Context context) {
    String currentApp = "Null";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context
                .getSystemService("usagestats");
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(
                UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
        if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey())
                        .getPackageName();
            }
        }
    } else {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        currentApp = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();

    }
    return currentApp;
}
```

Comment: How do you actually call your printForegroundTask() method?  I'm not following this: "But when I swipe the notification bar, it will take the name of the application package running in the notification bar"

Comment: I call it from service. that method will get the name of the application package is opened up.
But the problem is when I swipe down the notification bar. That application is active, it will take the name of the application package, I just want to get the name of the application package is open in the current.

Comment: Can you post that code as well so I can set it up just like you have it?

Comment: In service: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de51da1d5c6e99923df2 .how to get action swipe the notification bar.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is compiling for you.  This line is not valid:  
`UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context
                .getSystemService("usagestats");`   
To compile, I need to change "usagestats" to the constant:  
`UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context
                    .getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE)`

Comment: right. while running to granted.
Intent intent = new Intent (
Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity (intent); the problem now is probably get events swipe down the notification bar
because methods printForegroundTask named packages will get all the running applications.
I just want to get the name of the application package to open on.

Comment: Did the above change fix the initial problem you are having?  (I know the code as I changed it above runs on Android 6.)  It seems like you have a new problem now not specific to Android 6?)